# How can I have multiple URL requests to fetch a single type of entity in AFIncrementalStore?

Tags: afnetworking, afincrementalstore

Let's suppose I have a Core Data model using `AFIncrementalStore`, and I have multiple REST API endpoints for retrieving a list of objects of that model.  I can override `-requestForFetchRequest:withContext:` in `AFHTTPClient` like so:

```
- (NSURLRequest *)requestForFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest *)fetchRequest
                         withContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {

    NSMutableURLRequest *mutableURLRequest = nil;
    if ([fetchRequest.entityName isEqualToString:@"Post"]) {
        mutableURLRequest = [self requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"/posts/foo" parameters:nil];
    }
    return mutableURLRequest;
}
```

In this snippet, I retrieve `Post` objects at `/posts/foo`, but I also need to retrieve another set from `/posts/bar`.

How can I do this?  The only solution I see is to make two models: one for `foo` and one for `bar`, but repeating yourself is lame, and there may be many more API endpoints that get `Post` objects for me that I'll need to support.  Is there some other approach that I'm missing?

Comment: How do you decide if you want `/posts/foo` or `/posts/bar`?  For example, are those Post objects by different users?  Can you inspect `fetchRequest` to determine whether you're currently looking for `foo` or `bar` posts?

Comment: In my case, the API I'm talking to has a screen where I need to request both Foo and Bar Posts to list in a single table view.  My post model does have a property indicating which type it is, so perhaps I could look at `fetchRequest.predicate.predicateFormat` and determine that way?

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like in your case, you need to inspect `fetchRequest` more closely than just looking at `entityName`.  You can also look at `fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch` or possibly other things depending on your data model.  You'll still need to send two requests, so just make sure it can tell the difference.

Comment: Also: it sounds like your `requestForFetchRequest:withContext:` method might get really big.  You might want to consider a more generic pattern in which you get your `NSManagedObject` subclass, and ask that to return a fetch request.

Comment: That's brilliant!  I can't easily change `requestForFetchRequest:withContext` as that's part of `AFIncrementalStore`, but I can probably refactor cruft out pretty easily.  If you post this as an answer, I can give you the credit for it.  Otherwise, I'll answer it myself when I have it fully working later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inspect `fetchRequest` more closely than just looking at `entityName`. You can also look at `fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch` or possibly other things depending on your data model. You'll still need to send two requests, so just make sure your AFNetworking subclass can tell the difference.

Also: it sounds like your `requestForFetchRequest:withContext:` method might get really big. You might want to consider a more generic pattern in which you get your `NSManagedObject` subclass, and ask that to return a fetch request.